# knitr/beamer Legacy files no longer compile

Tags: r, latex, rstudio, knitr, beamer

I have a collection of old `.Rnw` files from ~2015 that were largely based on `.tex`  files for Beamer presentations. I used `knitr` mainly to include `R` code & output where needed, translate Rnw -> tex & then compile to PDF. This all worked within R Studio at the time.  It doesn't now, and I can't figure out why not or how to fix it.

One such file `.Rnw` begins like this:

```
\documentclass[10pt,table]{beamer} 

\input{inputs/beamer-setup}
\input{inputs/defs}

<<echo=FALSE>>=
source("Rprofile.R")
knitrSet("CFA-SEM")
@

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}
...
```

In R Studio now, I click on `Compile PDF`, but I get the error message:

```
(chunk 1) Argument is of length zero
```

Do I have to change all chunks from the old style to the new style,

````
```{r echo=FALSE}
...
```
````

I'm not sure exactly what `Compile PDF` does in R Studio.  What are commands I can use to find out what the problem is and how to correct it?

**Edit** Here is a complete MWE:

```
\documentclass[10pt,table]{beamer} 

%\input{inputs/beamer-setup}
%\input{inputs/defs}


\renewenvironment{knitrout}{\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{.9}}{}

<<echo=FALSE>>=
source("Rprofile.R")
knitrSet("CFA-SEM")
#.locals$chXX <- NULL
@

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}
\SweaveOpts{concordance=TRUE}
%\SweaveOpts{concordance=TRUE}

\title[CFA \& SEM]{Confirmatory Factor Analysis\\ \& Structural Equation Models}
\subtitle{Lecture 1: Overview \& Path Analysis}
\author{Michael Friendly}
\date[SCS] % (optional)
{SCS Short Course, May, 2019}

\begin{frame}[plain]
    \titlepage
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

In the output I get:

```
Writing to file testing1.tex
Processing code chunks with options ...
 1 : keep.source term verbatim (testing1.Rnw:9)
Loading required package: knitr

Error:  chunk 1 
Error in if (format == "latex") { : argument is of length zero
Execution halted
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. Thanks.

Comment: I believe you are using Sweave instead of knitr: http://stackoverflow.com/q/27592837/559676 Please let me know if I'm wrong and I'll reopen it.

Comment: That indeed was the problem.  Not sure how, but this project set the option for Sweave.  Also added: `% !Rnw weave = knitr` to make sure.